# Rails - Converting ransack result to xls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, ransack

I already tried:

```
<%= link_to "Download Excel File", yours_path(params.merge(:format => 'xls')) %>
```

which does not take into account the search form I have done on the same screen (it downloads everything).

Search form (works perfectly well, I get the right results on the page):

```
<%= search_form_for @q, url: yours_path do |f| %>

<div>
<%= f.search_field :last_name_cont, placeholder: "Type a last name" %>
</div>
```

I also already tried:

```
<a href="/yours_path.xls?<%= request.fullpath.split("?")[1]  %>">make xls</a>
```

which tries to use the URL to only download the right results but it downloads everything.

Index:

```
def index
    @q = Member.ransack(params[:q])
end
```

I would like to download only the result from ransack instead of all the objects.

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem

Answer (score 1):

Use this gem axlsx_rails for xlsx output and templates.
https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails/blob/master/README.md

Comment: This doesn't address the question - given you already have an output/template, then how to ensure that only the ransack results are applied to those templates?